# How to add a number to each image in a slider/gallery?

Tags: jquery

In OpenCart 3.0.2.0, with Journal2 theme, on the product page, there's a gallery that shows a large main image + additional images.

Here's the code for the additional images:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <a class="swiper-slide" {% if journal2.settings.get('product_page_gallery_carousel') %} style="width: {{ 100 / journal2.settings.get('product_page_additional_width', 5) }}%" {% endif %} href="{{ image.popup }}" title="{{ heading_title }}">
        <img src="{{ image.thumb }}" title="{{ heading_title }}" alt="{{ heading_title }}" itemprop="image"/>
     </a>
{% endfor %}
```

What I need to do is, add a **number** to each thumbnail. So the 1st additional thumbnail has a "1" on it, the 2nd one has a "2", and so on.

I'll format its appearance later with CSS, but I don't know enough PHP to figure out how to create these numbers in the first place.

If I can see a code example, I can figure it out from there. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP Twig? If so, you can use the Twig [loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).

If you want the first thumbnail to have a 1, you can use `loop.index`. If you want to put the number before your image, you can try this:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <a class="swiper-slide" {% if journal2.settings.get('product_page_gallery_carousel') %} style="width: {{ 100 / journal2.settings.get('product_page_additional_width', 5) }}%" {% endif %} href="{{ image.popup }}" title="{{ heading_title }}">
        {{ loop.index }}. <img src="{{ image.thumb }}" title="{{ heading_title }}" alt="{{ heading_title }}" itemprop="image"/>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I added a period after the index number because I'm assuming you want periods after the numbers. Obviously, the period isn't necessary.

I hope this helps.